Offset getUsedRange in Office Script with a starting address
Need a sub-range of the used range (sheet.getUsedRange()) starting from a specific address (ex. A10)?


Here is the first option Copilot and I came up with:



function getUsedRange(sheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet, startAddress: string): ExcelScript.Range {
    let startCell = sheet.getRange(startAddress);

    // Get the row and column indices of the starting cell
    let startRow = startCell.getRowIndex();
    let startColumn = startCell.getColumnIndex();

    // Get the used range of the worksheet
    let usedRange = sheet.getUsedRange();

    // Calculate the number of rows from the starting cell to the end of the used range
    let rowCount = usedRange.getRowIndex() + usedRange.getRowCount() - startRow;
    let columnCount = usedRange.getColumnIndex() + usedRange.getColumnCount() - startColumn;

    // Get the range starting from provided address to the end of the used range
    let customUsedRange = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(startRow, startColumn, rowCount, columnCount);

    return customUsedRange;
}




Another option is to construct a new range with the start address and the last cell of the used range:



let customUsedRange = sheet.getRange(startAddress + ":" + sheet.getUsedRange().getLastCell().getAddress());



